# Collection of Robin Hood stories told in a much older form of english

Tags: story-identification, robin-hood

I remember reading when I was a kid a collection of Robin Hood stories. I really enjoyed it, but the only defining trait I can remember is that it was narrated in VERY old English style, although I'm pretty sure that this wasn't actually very old English writing, but more of an attempt at stylization to add some flavor to the stories. Does anyone know off the top of their head where I could find this collection?

**Edit:** Upon more research, it appears to be Howard Pyle's [The Merry Adventures of Robin Hood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Merry_Adventures_of_Robin_Hood) written in 1883. Wikipedia describes it as a work that *"compiles traditional material into a coherent narrative in a colorful, invented "old English" idiom that preserves some flavor of the ballads, and adapts it for children."*. Per the comments, it does look like it's historical fiction.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is not about science fiction or fantasy

Comment: @Richard Robin Hood isn't fantasy?

Comment: @Xantec - I'm reasonably certain it's historical fiction.

Comment: @Richard doesn't he fall into the same category as like Arthur legends? He is quite unbelievable.

Comment: @Himarm last we discussed, [it seemed to be work-dependent](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6384/are-questions-about-robin-hood-on-topic). Folklore is definitely on-topic at [Mythology.SE](http://mythology.stackexchange.com/), but I don't know if they allow identification requests for specific works

Comment: @Himarm - I'm going to say no. There's at least a school of thought that he [actually existed](http://www.historic-uk.com/HistoryUK/HistoryofEngland/Robin-Hood/). Feel free to ask on meta though, if you want a second opinion

Comment: @JasonBaker yeah i just saw that post too, so this would be ontopic, until it found that the works would be off topic?lol